# Como transformar o texto em imagem

Tags: android, imagem, textview

Na minha aplicação, tenho um listView que exibe as informações do banco de dados, quero que ao carregar a listView a String de um dos TextView seja substituída por uma imagem. De acordo com o texto apresentado, aparecerá uma imagem diferente. Tem como fazer isso e como seria?

O código é só para representar o que quero na aplicação, pois não funciona!

```
    switch (textView1.getText()) {
        case textView1.getText("carro") ;            
    textView1.setBackground(R.drawable.image1);  
            break;

        case textView2.getText("moto") ;
     textView2.setBackground(R.drawable.image2);
            break;

     case textView3.getText("caminhao") ;
     textView3.setBackground(R.drawable.image3);
            break;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para colocar uma imagem como *background* de um *TextView* use o seguinte código:

```
textView.setBackground(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.image));
```

Se estiver a usar a API level 21 ou superior use:

```
textView.setBackground(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.image, getTheme()));
```

Comment: O código que estou tentando usar é esse, mas está dando erro

Comment: Qual é o erro ?

Comment: Ao chamar o `setTvImage();` a aplicação dá erro e encerra, talve eu esteja fazendo a chamada em um local errado ou o meu código que não funciona mesmo!

Comment: Sem saber qual é o erro é difícil poder ajudar. Você obteve a referência para o TextView tvImage: `tvImage = (TextView)findViewById(....);`?

Comment: Sim, obtive a referência para o textView tvImage.

Comment: Será que o problema pode ser por estar usando o if ao invés do switch case?

Comment: Sem você postar o *log* de erros é impossível saber onde está o problema.

Comment: Postei agora o log

Comment: O erro diz que tvImage é nulo. Com os últimos desenvolvimentos esta pergunta está se tornando numa totalmente diferente. Tal fica fora do modo de funcionamento do site. O correcto a fazer é colocar esta pergunta como estava no inicio(revertê-la) e fazer outra com o código e o log. Considere votar/aceitar a resposta caso julgue por bem fazê-lo